# TypeError: (0 , _rulesUnitTesting.clearFirestoreData) is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs, firebase-security

i'm trying to follow this [setup tutorial](https://eliteionic.com/tutorials/using-tdd-to-test-deploy-firestore-security-rules/) of Firebase rules unit testing as much as I can but i'm getting errors. Its the setup for Angular and i'm using React so its not far-fetched that i missed something.

Here is my code:

```
import {
  assertFails,
  assertSucceeds,
  initializeAdminApp,
  initializeTestApp,
  apps,
  clearFirestoreData,
} from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing";

const PROJECT_ID = "My_Project";

const getFirestore = () =>
  initializeTestApp({ projectId: PROJECT_ID }).firestore();
const getAdminFirestore = () =>
  initializeAdminApp({ projectId: PROJECT_ID }).firestore();

describe("Our social app", () => {
  it("Understand basic addition", () => {
    expect(2 + 2).toEqual(4);
  });

  describe("Firestore security rules", () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      await clearFirestoreData({ projectId: PROJECT_ID });
    });
    it("can not read from the messages collection", async () => {
      const db = getFirestore();
      const testDoc = db.collection("messages").doc("testDoc");
      await assertFails(testDoc.get());
    });
    afterAll(async () => {
      const cleanUpApps = apps().map((app) => app.delete());
      await Promise.all(cleanUpApps);
    });
  });
});
```

But i get the error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _rulesUnitTesting.clearFirestoreData) is not a function
```

or i get this one:

```
TypeError: (0 , _rulesUnitTesting.initializeTestApp) is not a function

      11 |
      12 | const getFirestore = () =>
    > 13 |   initializeTestApp({ projectId: PROJECT_ID }).firestore();
         |                    ^
      14 | const getAdminFirestore = () =>
      15 |   initializeAdminApp({ projectId: PROJECT_ID }).firestore();
```

when i comment out the `beforeEach` paragraph of code.

```
"@firebase/rules-unit-testing": "^2.0.7",
```

What is producing these 2 errors?